# Trying to copy data from one sheet to another in a different pattern

Tags: indexing

Need a formula for the following if there is one.

Copying data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 to fill in passenger names for a trip manifest in the following pattern, taking 2 names from each row and putting them in order in 1 column:

F9=Y2, F10=Z2, F11=Y3, F12=Z3, F13=Y4, F14=Z4

.....and so on...I have hundreds of cells to fill and have wracked my brain and researched for days! I know this can't be this hard!

Comment: What programming language do you use and in what format are the values?

Comment: sorry, I'm fairly new to all this.  Using google sheets and the cells to be copied are names of passengers. I have Sheet 1 of registrations that have Room 1, Passenger 1 and Passenger 2 in consecutive columns (Y2,Z2), Room 2, Passenger 1 and Passenger 2 in consecutive columns (Y3,Z3)  and need to create a passenger list on Sheet 2 with all passengers in one column in order by room, F9 = Room1, Passenger 1, F10 = Room1, Passenger 2, F11= Room 2 Passenger 1, F12=room 2 , Passenger 2....

Answer (score 0):

## Math

We want to find a function that maps from a cell in sheet 2 to Room and passenger in Sheet 1.

```
cell: (room x passenger)
```

You can see a pattern in these numbers.

An intermediate formula is as follows. This maps from a cell in sheet 2, to the indices of the room and persons.

```
Given a cell index: i
room = round((i - 8) / 2) // -8 because we want to start with room1 at cell F9
passenger = (i mod 2) + 1
```

These formulas will just return the indices. So we have to map them to the actual cells in sheet 1.

```
Given Room r and person p: (both previously calculated indices)
person_cell_letter = (Y + p - 1) // if this is possible. or if statement
// Goal is to get Y for person1 and Z for person2
person_cell_number = r + 1
Cell = person_cell_letter + person_cell_number
```

I hope these formulas are correct or at least lead you in the right direction. If you have any question you are welcome to ask it in a comment.

## Code

These formulas where more like pseudo code instead of real code. depending of the language you gonna use you have to adjust these formulas.

### python

If you want this to do this automatically for you, you could take a language like python. It is easy to use and has good libraries for such stuff. I probably would first convert the sheets into another format like CSV or xlsx. Otherwise, you have to use the google API which can be difficult to use. 
You can then use a library like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to work with this data in python. [read excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) manipulate it and then [write back to excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). It should then be possible to somehow convert this back go google sheets.

### Google sheets script

Another approach possibly easier would be to use [Google sheets script](https://zapier.com/learn/google-sheets/google-apps-script-tutorial/#started). but I have never used it and can't say anything about it.